# get size of parent layout/fragment while drawing it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-canvas

I have a custom view that I'm using canvas to be able to draw on it what I want, this view inside a scrollview that take match_parent for each width and height and also my custom view take match_parent for each width and height

I want to know the size of the scrollview to be able to draw only inside the available space that I have

I have tried onLayout, onMeasure but nothing works with me

Can any one please help?

Comment: try below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656139/android-get-height-of-the-parent-layouut

Comment: I have used display matrix to get all screen width and height, but it make a great problem when I add my custom view with another controls above and bellow it, my control is not showing complete

Comment: see Canvas.getClipBounds method

Comment: Actually I'm drawing on bitmap to speed up the scrolling of my view, so in the first of my draw method I create the bitmap with my display matrix width and height and then create a canvas from that bitmap, so I think this will not work with me

Comment: I have found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845197/android-get-fragment-width, and it gives my the width and height of my fragment, but it draw an empty fragment, can any one tell me what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem using

onGlobalLayout Method, and I also inherit Viewgroup not View and implement onLayoutMethod, to make element shown in my fragement

Thanks all